# Oracle SQL No Data in series

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query result that is almost perfect except for the fact that in the result I don't always have a complete series in my muli-series data that I am trying to eventually show in a report and chart.

```
NAME             MONTH          COST
----------------------------------------
name1            2                 100
name1            3                 80
name2            1                 60
name3            2                 30
----------------------------------------
```

Here is query:

```
select Name, month, count(*) as cost
from table1
group by name, month
order by month, name
```

What I have here isn't one simple set of data, but a series of data. For each month, I have a set of users and sales.

I can fix this on my application side by doing a few loops and getting the distinct values for Name and Month.

I'd like to learn how to create my Oracle query to get a result set that looks something like this

```
NAME             MONTH          COST
----------------------------------------
name1            1                 0
name1            2                 100
name1            3                 80
name2            1                 60
name2            2                 0
name2            3                 0
name3            1                 0
name3            2                 30
name3            3                 0
----------------------------------------
```

Comment: Can you please mention your SQL query here ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with a `cross join` and then a `left outer jon`:

```
select n.name, m.month, coalesce(t.cost, 0) as cost
from (select distinct name from table t) n cross join
     (select distinct month from table t) m left join
     table t
     on t.name = n.name and t.month = m.month
order by n.name, m.month;
```

Comment: This works great without having to create a view. 


   `select n.name, m.month, coalesce(t.cost, 0) as cost
    from (select distinct name from table1 t) n cross join
         (select distinct month from table1 t) m left join
         (select Name, month, count(*) as cost from table1 group by name, month order by month, name) t
          on t.name = n.name and t.month = m.month
    order by n.name, m.month;`